# Ошибка (1146, "Table 'db_name.125059735_gjt' doesn't exist") при обращении к таблице MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Использую Python3 и MySQLdb, пытаюсь обратиться к уже созданной таблице, которая имеет имя: `'125059735_gjt'`

создаю запрос:

```
tablename_value = str(((user_id) + '_gjt'))
query = ("""INSERT INTO `%s` (user_id, time, description, status) VALUES (`%s`, `%s`, `%s`, 1);""")
cursor.execute (query, (tablename_value, user_p, time, reason,))
```

мне выдается ошибка:

> (1146, "Table 'db_name.'125059735_gjt'' doesn't exist")

Не могу сообразить, в чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А какое значение находится в `tablename_value`? И что будет в консоли при `print("""INSERT INTO \`%s\` (user_id, time, description, status) VALUES (\`%s\`, \`%s\`, \`%s\`, 1);""" % (tablename_value, user_p, time, reason,))`?. PS. думаю так проще будет: `tablename_value = '{}_gjt'.format(user_id)`, хотя если `user_id` это строка, то `tablename_value = user_id + '_gjt'`

Comment: Если создавать запрос """INSERT INTO `%s` (user_id, time, description, status) VALUES (`%s`, `%s`, `%s`, 1);""" % (tablename_value, user_p, time, reason,), ошибка - not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Это значит, что у вас в строке `%s` больше чем параметров, которые подставляете в `%`. Ну ладно, на ваш вопрос ответ есть, значит дальнейшее обсуждение бессмысленное :)

Comment: Спасибо и вам )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имена объектов (таблиц, представлений, столбцов, etc.) нельзя параметризировать. Параметризировать можно только литералы.

Workaround:

```
query = ("""INSERT INTO `{}` (user_id, time, description, status) VALUES (`%s`, `%s`, `%s`, 1);""".format(tablename_value))

cursor.execute (query, (user_p, time, reason,))
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!